# Shiny R Input - Add to end of data frame continuously

Tags: r, shiny

I currently have the following shiny app and the intention is to add the text input as a new row into the dataset. Currently, the new text input is overriding the old input instead of appending to the end. I understand that's happening because I'm referring to df in the eventReactive, which is the originally seeded empty data frame, but my various attempts around that have led to errors.

Does somebody know of a way to fix that? Bonus if there is a way to clear the text input box after hitting the submit button.

```
library(shiny)

colClasses = c("factor", "numeric")
col.names = c("Player", "1")

df <- read.table(text = "",
                 colClasses = colClasses,
                 col.names = col.names)
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Random Draft Order"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput("AddPlayer",
                        "Add Player",
                        ""),
            actionButton("submit", ("Submit"))
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           tableOutput("racingbars")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    

    actionButton("submit", ("Submit"))
    
    FinalData = eventReactive(input$submit,{
        df = rbind(df, data.frame("Player" = input$AddPlayer, "X1" = ""))
    })
    

    output$racingbars <- renderTable({
                 FinalData()    
        })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this creating a `reactiveVal` that will store the data.

First, you can initialize your data.frame `df` as a `reactiveVal`:

```
df <- reactiveVal(data.frame(Player = character(), 
                             X1 = character()))
```

To update the `reactiveVal` you can use:

```
df(new_dat)
```

And to reference the data later on, use:

```
df()
```

In your example, an `observeEvent` can be triggered by your submit button. When that happens, you can add your row of data to the `reactiveVal` data.frame similar to what you have done. The `output` can then point to the `reactiveVal` data.frame to display the data.

I also added `updateTextInput` to the `observeEvent` to clear the text input after the submit button is pressed. Note this requires `session` in the server function declaration.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df <- reactiveVal(data.frame(Player = character(), 
                               X1 = character()))
  
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    new_dat <- rbind(df(), data.frame(Player = input$AddPlayer, X1 = ""))
    df(new_dat)
    updateTextInput(session, "AddPlayer", value = "")
  })
  
  output$racingbars <- renderTable({
    df()   
  })
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly well. I'll have to take a bit of time and learn more about reactive programming, which I find difficult to intuit.

Comment: @CcS Great! Glad to hear. I added a bit more explanation on `reactiveVal` as well. More on reactivity [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html) and [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/reactivity-objects.html).